# JQuery - Responsive Navigation on tab Overflow using cookies and Window width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

here is an interesting question.

I have a navigation bar that looks like this:

```
< div id = "main_nav" >
< ul >
< li id = "Tab1" > Home < / li >
< li id = "Tab2" > Home1 < / li >
< li id = "Tab3" > Home2 < / li >
< li id = "etc" > etc etc < / li >
...
< / ul >
< / div >
```

So the #main_nav has fixed width of 980px with overflow hidden and tabs are inline block.
When the screen width decreased in size, the tabs are overflowing and are beyond the screen view, thous are hidden.

To make it fun, I created a property to catch the last tab and see if it is overflowing, if it does, fire the event so the tab changes the from block to something else like responsive design.

Here is the code:

```
$( window ).on( 'resize', function(){ resize(); } );

function resize() {
var pageWidth = $ ( "#main_nav" ).width();
var elementWidth = $ ( "#tab14" ).width();
var elementLeft = $ ( "#tab14" ).position().left;

if ( pageWidth - ( elementWidth + elementLeft ) < 0 ) { 
$ ( 'ul > li' ) .css ( { 'float': 'left' } ); 
}
else {
$ ( 'ul > li' ) .css ( { 'float': '' } );
}
}
```

The problem: The tabs starts flickering as it checks if #tab14 is overflown and on refresh you need to resize window to get to that state.

The question:
1. Not related to the issue but, what is a good Jquery counter to find the number of the last tab automatically and fill in to the $("#tab NUMBER?").width();

1. To avoid flickering, I tried the Timer, none worked. Do any of you know how to Save a Cookie of the Screen Width when the Tab event (tab overflowing) fired? So I can fire the else event only after that screen width reached to return tab to its original shape.

Your input is very appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all, here is my own solution:

**Responsive Navigation on Overflow:**

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
        ress_nav();
});

function more_nav() {
    $('#main_nav li').css({'width': ''});
    $('#main_nav li').css({'float': ''});
}

function less_nav() {
    $('#main_nav li').css({'width': '50%'});
    $('#main_nav li').css({'float': 'left'});
}

function ress_nav() {
    var lastTab = $("#main_nav li:last-child");
    var winWidth = $(window).width();
    var elWidth = $(lastTab).width();
    var elLeft = $(lastTab).position().left; 

    if (winWidth - (elWidth + elLeft) < 0) {
        $.cookie('winWidth', winWidth);
        less_nav();
    }
    else if ($(window).width() > $.cookie('winWidth')){
        $.removeCookie('winWidth', winWidth);
        more_nav();
    }
}

if ($(window).width() > $.cookie('winWidth')) {more_nav()} else {less_nav()}
```

Hope it helps anyone looking for such a function.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can save cookies in JavaScript by using the `window.localStorage` method. Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage for more information.

Comment: Hi, thanks, I do know how to save the cookie, but the question is how to know what screen size was it when the event fired and how to actually know and connect Screen Width info with Tab Overflow event...